# two ways creating functions compared in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this snippet of function

```
fun getNewIntent(context: Context, following: Boolean, userId: String): Intent {
    val intent = Intent(context, UsersActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(FOLLOW, following)
    intent.putExtra(USER, userId)
    return intent
}
```

that can be written also like this

```
fun getNewIntent(context: Context, following: Boolean, userId: String): Intent =
        Intent(context, UsersActivity::class.java).also {
            it.putExtra(FOLLOW, following)
            it.putExtra(USER, userId)
        }
```

and example in a case it was only 1 parameter

```
fun getNewIntent(context: Context, userId: String): Intent =
        Intent(context, UsersActivity::class.java).apply { putExtra(USER, userId) }
```

which one is better? and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are basically equivalent. I would go for whatever is the most readable to you and/or your team.

I personally like the direct assigments if it is clear enough what is done in the function. Usually that's the case if it's a one-liner or if an initialization is followed by something like `.apply` (so basically just relatively short). For your functions I would actually introduce something like the following:

```
inline fun <reified T> newIntent(context: Context, applyToIntent : Intent.() -> Unit = {}) = Intent(context, T::class.java).apply(applyToIntent)
```

which is then reusable for several activities. Usage could then be as simple as:

```
newIntent<UsersActivity>(context) {
  putExtra(FOLLOW, following)
  putExtra(USER, userId)
}
```

Or if you really require your current function (I don't see a real reason for it though), it stays still simple enough:

```
fun getNewIntent(context: Context, following: Boolean, userId: String) = newIntent<UsersActivity>(context) {
    putExtra(FOLLOW, following)
    putExtra(USER, userId)
}
```

Comment: the only way that you still need to have the `getNewIntent()` in your companion object is to have there the consts of your arguments

Comment: companion object of class UsersActivity is like that

`
    companion object {
        const val FOLLOW = "FOLLOWING"
        const val USER = "USER"

        fun getNewIntent(context: Context, following: Boolean, userId: String) =
                ...
    }
`

Comment: it is not easy to write it in comment :)

Comment: I think I got you.... well... that sample should work nonetheless... you just need to ensure that you import that constant values, if not already done so...

Comment: Private consts but removed the word private from comment

Comment: you skipped the most essential one ;-) ok... if that's private and you are not willing to open it up, nor move it to another place, well... then yes... you require that local function at the bottom to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

No difference. Second variant must be use if you can write `return` in one line instead better use first. Also in second variant you can remove this part `: Intent`.

Also can check this - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html